# Rails | how to access correctly to an object that are not logged

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user table on my Rails app. These users send email to contacts. Those contacts are stored into my db but they do not have account.
I want to let them unsubscribe to those emails.

What I did for now :

- i add a subscription column to those contacts
- i create a hash to find them well

My contact controller :

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :add_unsubscribe_hash

private
def add_unsubscribe_hash
self.unsubscribe_hash = SecureRandom.hex
end
```

my contact controller

```
def unsubscribe
@contact = Contact.find_by_unsubscribe_hash(params[:unsubscribe_hash])
@contact.update_attribute(:subscription, false)
authorize(:contact, :unsubscribe)
end
```

my route :

```
put 'contacts/unsubscribe/:unsubscribe_hash' => 'contacts#unsubscribe', :as => 'unsubscribe'
```

my link into the mail template :

```
href="<%= link_to 'Unsubscribe', unsubscribe_url(@unsubscribe_hash), method: :put %>"
```

I read a lot about this kind of problem, try so much thing, but i do not find a good way to make this work
Having error as "possible unmatched constraints: [:unsubscribe_hash]" or nil for the subscription_hash : my app do not find the @contact or the unsubscribe_hash

Comment: Did you created a mailer class? If not you have to create a mailer class and call that in the controller

Comment: `href="<%= link_to 'Unsubscribe', unsubscribe_url(@unsubscribe_hash), method: :put %>"` will just result in broken HTML. `link_to` creates an entire `<a>` tag - so why you're doing this is kind of puzzling.

Comment: I’m using a third email service, not actionmailer.

Comment: Also `method: :put` relies on Rails UJS to create a form in javascript and post it. It will not work in a mailer as mail clients oftent don't allow JS. You need to use a GET route.

Comment: I’m gonna edit this asap. Firstly, I need to find a way to having the contact object pass to the mailer, and allow them to unsub with the good hash that the app generated